# Is there a trick to using $_POST on amazonS3?

Tags: php, post, amazon-s3

I have a simple php email form where the form is validated and submitted through an ajax call to an email.php. It works fine on my own server, but on Amazon S3 I get the error: `MethodNotAllowedThe specified method is not allowed against this resource.OBJECTPOST2871412DE...` and then a continuing string of numbers and letters.

my php file is as follows

```
<?php

$to = "person@domain.com";
$subject = "Message from ".$_POST['my_name'];

$person = $_POST['my_name'];
$email = $_POST['my_email'];
$comments = $_POST['my_comments'];



$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n" .
         "Reply-To: ".$email. "\r\n";

$message = "Entry from: ".$person." (".$email.")\n\n Comments: ".$comments;

$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


?>
```

Here is the ajax call (w the absolute php url censored):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#emailSubmitBtn").click(function(){

        if ( $("#contactForm").valid() ) {

            var myName = $('#my_name').val();
            var myEmail = $('#my_email').val();
            var myComments = $('#my_comments').val(); 

            var dataString = 'my_name='+ myName + '&my_email=' + myEmail + '&my_comments=' + myComments;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://####.s3.amazonaws.com/email.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#contact').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<p>Thank you for submitting the form!</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: anyone care to explain the downvotes? Do we lose points for being stupid? Or for poorly phrased questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 can't execute PHP files, so what you're trying to do simply won't work.

You can post a file to an S3 bucket (rather than a specific file URL, hence the allowed method error), but you can't run code there. It's the **Simple** ***Storage*** Service.